# jQuery Mobile Listview not refreshing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

Having trouble initializing or refreshing my ul - the method I use in my code sample works in another function I'm using but not here... I must be missing something?

```
$(data).find("#HospitalDescriptions").find('th').filter(function(){
  if (this.innerHTML !== '') {
    var bgcolor = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
    var txtcolor = $( this ).css( "color" );
        if (bgcolor !== ''){
            $('#information').append('<div id="alertColors"><ul><li><span style="background-color:' + bgcolor + ';color:' + txtcolor + ';">' + this.innerHTML + '</span></li></ul></div>');
        } else {
            $('#information').append('<li>' + this.innerHTML + '</li>');
        }
  }
    $('#information').listview('refresh');   // not working!
});
```

here is my HTML the ul is created in code:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="hospitals" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>HOSP-HEADER</h1>
        <a class="ui-btn-right" id="infoButton" onclick="$('#locations').listview('refresh');">Refresh</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b" id="regions">   

        <div data-role="content">
            <h4>Information</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="information">
                <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h4>Regions I, II, III</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="region3">
                <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h4>Region IV</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="region4">
                <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h4>Region V</h4>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="region5">
                <!-- AJAX CONTENT -->
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Uhm, does not .innerHTML return a DOM object? If so, then it is no wonder that the if query does mostly fail.

Comment: the if query doesn't fail, results are fine, it is just not formatting in jquery mobile and shows as a standard li

Comment: You should probably use `.each` instead of `.filter` for both the legibility and stability of your code. `.

Comment: my code works, .filter achieves desired results, looking for solution to the formatting issue?

Comment: Do you have `data-role="listview"` set on the appropriate element?

Comment: I didn't on my previous code and it worked fine, I just tried your suggestion and still no luck... I'm sure it's a timeing thing, just can't pin it down.

Comment: Show your HTML markup.

Comment: You're inserting `ul` inside `ul`, it will result a nested listview. Post your html markup.

Comment: Thanks that was it... forgot I had separated out div to ul fixed... I'll update post to show fix if others have same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lost track of #ID. The #information was a ul not div as origionally created. removed nesting div inside ul :

```
$(data).find("#HospitalDescriptions").find('th').filter(function(){
    if (this.innerHTML !== '') {
    var bgcolor = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
    var txtcolor = $( this ).css( "color" );
        if (bgcolor !== ''){
            $('#information').append('<li><span style="background-color:' + bgcolor + ';color:' + txtcolor + ';">' + this.innerHTML + '</span></li>');
        } else {
            $('#information').append('<li>' + this.innerHTML + '</li>');
        }
    }
    $('#information').listview('refresh');
});
```